# Kohana v3 ACL A2 with database support

Tags: frameworks, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I am using Kohana V 3.0.3.

I was looking for ACL library and found from http://dev.kohanaphp.com/projects A2 Kohana's ACL module.

Apparently it's found that, it manages Roles,Resources and Rules using config file and authenticate object basis.

I want it to be dynamic, like Resources and Rules should be loaded from database dynamically if valid user logs in. Auth part is done now looking for ACL part.

Is it possible to use same A2 module with database or need to rewrite own logic?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have used Kohana's ACL module as a base and written wrapper child class to fetch data from database. Using combination of both now its serving my requirements.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you came up with for pulling ACL from the db?

Comment: yes would you mind sharing that. I also am in crucial need.thanks